# Why does NSDateFormatter not return nil when given empty string ("")

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsdateformatter

I have a quick question.
According to apple official documentation
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/dateFromString:

NSDateFormatter.dateFromString(String) would return

> A date representation of string interpreted using the receiver’s current settings. If dateFromString: can not parse the string, returns nil.

Then I when I give it an empty string "", should it return nil?
When I do this in the playground

```
let date = ""
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"
print(dateFormatter.dateFromString(date))
```

It gave me

```
"Optional(1999-12-31 15:00:00 +0000)\n"
```

Is this happen to be a normal behaviour?
Or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you

Comment: I agree that's a little strange, but the result makes sense given that your timezone is probably GMT+9. If your date format was `yyyy-MM-dd`, you would have gotten `nil`.

Comment: You are right, when I change it to "yyyy-MM-dd", NSDateFormatter gave me nil. I also think that it is very weird that it response differently when given different date format, which should just be how it parse the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If dateFromString: can not parse the string, returns nil

The simple answer is, the `dateFromString` does manage to parse an empty `string`. If you try and put wrong data in the `string`, say `"0"` then you will get `nil`.

Why is it happening? I assume that it is just they way the class is written, since the date formatter does skip missing data and try to complete it. There is probably not a case for "all is missing".

Comment: An empty input string is accepted for the date format "yyyyMMdd" and for "yyyyMM", but *not* for the date format "yyyy". There are other cases where missing data is not just "completed". For example the "yyyyMMddHHmm" format does not accept the input "2015" or "20150101". – So this does not fully explain it.

Comment: Yes. I think that's what I said, **try to complete** the missing input. If it doesn't manage it returns nil.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly. If it's not possible to parse the string it will return `nil` but if you use an empty string it will return that date by default.

Change the `""` for `" "` or anything to fill it if it's `nil` what you want to obtain.